# Qt Can't link Qt library LINK2019

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors

I have this new project with only one file. I try to use some Qt objects. Compilation works fine, but I have errors at the link step. I have searched for several hours and haven't been able to find an answer.
I suppose the linker can't find the dll folder but I have no idea how to indicate a folder in that purpose...

Thanks for your help!

I am using the last Qt version (5.11.2) with MSVC2017

Here are the three files:

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);   
    QList<QSerialPortInfo> portList = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtSerialPort/qserialport.h>
#include "serial_manager.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    //QSerialPortInfo* serialInfo;
    Serial_manager* sr_mngr;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and the error:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: erreur : LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QSerialPortInfo::~QSerialPortInfo(void)" (__imp_??1QSerialPortInfo@@QEAA@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: void * __cdecl QSerialPortInfo::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQSerialPortInfo@@QEAAPEAXI@Z)
```

Comment: Does this help?  [QT linker error when adding class to basic QT GUI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044185/qt-linker-error-when-adding-class-to-basic-qt-gui-application)

Comment: Woo, never seen a non-English compiler before. :-)

Comment: @Ian yes it helped! That was the information I was not aware of, thank you!

Comment: The link by Ian was the answer to my question! [QT linker error when adding class to basic QT GUI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044185/qt-linker-error-when-adding-class-to-basic-qt-gui-application)